# How to find any matching record with multiple parameter .net core +mongodb

Tags: mongodb, .net-core

I have a requirement where i need to fetch the matching records when we pass multiple parameters. For example if i have four parameter coming from API but suppose user passed only two parameters and rest two are coming as null. In that case I need to find records matching with those not null parameters. If user pass all parameters then in that case I have to fetch all the records matching with all four parameters.

I am new with mongo

Comment: Can we see some code? Its impossible to give an answer without knowing what you have already tried

Answer (score 1):

You can easily build query like this:

```
public IEnumerable<MyType> GetFiltered(string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4)
{
  return collection.Find(item =>
    (p1 == null || item.P1 == p1) &&
    (p2 == null || item.P2 == p2) &&
    (p3 == null || item.P3 == p3) &&
    (p4 == null || item.P4 == p4)
  ).ToList();
}
```

Or by steps with IQueryable interface:

```
public IEnumerable<MyType> GetFiltered(string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4)
{
  var items = collection.AsQueryable();

  if (p1 != null)
    items = items.Where(x => x.P1 == p1);

  if (p2 != null)
    items = items.Where(x => x.P2 == p2);

  if (p3 != null)
    items = items.Where(x => x.P3 == p3);

  if (p4 != null)
    items = items.Where(x => x.P4 == p4);

  return items.ToList();
}
```

Or by steps with FilterDefinition:

```
public IEnumerable<MyType> GetFiltered(string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4)
{
  var builder = Builders<MyType>.Filter;
  List<FilterDefinition<MyType>> conditions = new List<FilterDefinition<MyType>>();

  if (p1 != null)
    conditions.Add(builder.Where(x => x.P1 == p1));

  if (p2 != null)
    conditions.Add(builder.Where(x => x.P2 == p2));

  if (p3 != null)
    conditions.Add(builder.Where(x => x.P3 == p3));

  if (p4 != null)
    conditions.Add(builder.Where(x => x.P4 == p4));

  return collection.Find(builder.And(conditions)).ToList();
}
```